# Does the unitization of a Banach algebra satisfy some universal property?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, definition, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a Banach algebra, and $A^e = A \times \Bbb C$ be its *unitization*, with multiplication defined as $$(a,p)\cdot(b,q) = (ab + pb + qa, pq)$$
$A^e$ is also a Banach algebra with $(0,1)$ as its unit. Does the unitization of a Banach algebra satisfy some *universal property*? I am hoping to define $A^e$ in a *"categorical way"*, whatever that means. Thanks for any insights!

Comment: At a guess, maybe it is the initial object in the category of all extensions of $A$ to a unital algebra?

Comment: @FShrike But what if the algzbra is already unital?

Comment: @Andromeda That's fair comment. I don't think there's a mistake in my answer though. Weird

Comment: Isn't this the same construction as the unitisation of a non-unital $\mathbb{C}$-algebra? That has a universal property: it is the left adjoint of the forgetful functor from the category of $\mathbb{C}$-algebras to the category of non-unital $\mathbb{C}$-algebras. (Note, this forgetful functor is faithful but not full!)

Answer (score 1):

Say $B$ is a complex unital Banach algebra with an injective linear homomorphism $\varphi:A\to B$. Claim: there is a unique morphism of unital Banach algebras $\psi:A^e\to B$ with $\psi(a,0)=\varphi$ for all $a\in A$ (i.e. $\psi$ uniquely takes the inclusion $A\hookrightarrow A^e$ into $\varphi$).

Well that's not too hard to show. Because $\psi(0,1)=\mathbf{1}_B$ the unit is demanded as well as linearity, so that $\psi(a,\lambda)=\psi(a,0)+\psi(0,\lambda)=\varphi(a)+\lambda\mathbf{1}_B$ is forced. So there is one and only one way to define $\psi$. Probably this is compatible with continuity considerations too. We could actually drop quite a lot here, e.g. the injectivity and the "homomorphism" aspect are irrelevant.

Idea: adjoining a unit $e$ demands also adjoining at least $\{a+\operatorname{span}(e):a\in A\}\sim A\times\Bbb C$. The most efficient way to do so is to just take $A\times\Bbb C$ itself.

Disclaimer: I kinda made this up. I don't know if this is the canonical universal property associated to $A^e$.